# Member function error while using template class as a value in std::map

Tags: c++, templates

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

class IVariantClass{
public:
  ~IVariantClass(){};
};

template<typename Type>
class VariantClass: public IVariantClass {
public:
  VariantClass(const Type& var):  var_{var}{}
  Type& GetVar() { return var_;}
private:
  Type var_;
};


int main() {
    std::map<int, double> var;

    std::map<std::string , std::shared_ptr<IVariantClass>> args_value;
    int x = 10;
    double y = 10.22;
    std::string str = "string";

    args_value["val1"] = std::make_shared<VariantClass<decltype(x)>>(x);
    args_value["val2"] = std::make_shared<VariantClass<decltype(y)>>(y);
    args_value["val3"] = std::make_shared<VariantClass<decltype(str)>>(str); 

    for (typename std::map<std::string , std::shared_ptr<IVariantClass>>::iterator it = args_value.begin(); it!=args_value.end(); ++it) { 
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second->GetVar() << "\n" ;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> : In function 'int main()':
>
> :36:54: error: 'using element_type = class IVariantClass' {aka
>   'class IVariantClass'} has no member named 'GetVar'
>
> 36 |         std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second->GetVar() << "\n";

Comment: Are you expecting polymorphic behavior? That's why the interface?

Comment: Hint: Think about the type of `second` in the loop. Is it really polymorphic? See: https://godbolt.org/z/ZnR2Dg.